# C# inserting a jpg file into an Outlook email message

Tags: c#, email, outlook, resources, jpeg

This is my first time posting a question although I have been lurking and learning from all of you for a while now.  I have been developing a C# Windows Form application that automates several day to day activities.  One of the simplest pieces of this application is really giving me a hard time.

I need to insert two jpg files into an Email that I am responding to.  I can accomplish this by pulling the files directly from the drive but would prefer them to be stored as a resource in the executable.  This way I can pass the EXE to others and they can use it also.  Here is an example of the code that works when it is stored locally.  what I would prefer to do however is replace @"H:\ISOIR\PhishMeIcon.jpg" with Resource1.PhishMeIconJPG .  I have seen several discussion about streams and converting the file to Byte format but this does not seem to interact well with Outlook.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Make sure you have the Email reporting the incident Open");

        string inc_num;

        inc_num = incident_number.Text;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application aPP = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(1);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)aPP.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder f = aPP.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inSpect = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem sMail = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem rMail = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment phishICO = null;


        try
        {
            inSpect = aPP.ActiveInspector();
            sMail = inSpect.CurrentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
            rMail = sMail.ReplyAll();
            phishICO = rMail.Attachments.Add(@"H:\ISOIR\PhishMeIcon.jpg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, "name");
            string imageCid = "PhishMeIcon.jpg@123";
            phishICO.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageCid);
            rMail.Subject = ("INC- ") + inc_num;
            rMail.HTMLBody = Resource1.SPAM_Response_P1 + String.Format("<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>", imageCid) + Resource1.SPAM_Response_P2 + rMail.HTMLBody;
            rMail.HTMLBody = rMail.HTMLBody.Replace("XXXX", inc_num);
            rMail.Save();

            MessageBox.Show("Your Email has been saved in your DRAFT Folder for review");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
                "An exception is occured in the code of add-in.");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sMail != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sMail);
            if (rMail != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rMail);
            if (inSpect != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inSpect);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I did this back in 2007 and wrote my only CodeProject article on it: [Embed HTML Email Images](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11774/Embed-HTML-Email-Images)

Comment: KiwiPiet, Thank you for such a quick response.  Your link was very helpful for another piece of my program but not quite what I am trying to accomplish.  Or, maybe I am just not getting it.  I am new to this type of interaction.  Instead of @"H:\ISOIR\PhishMeIcon.jpg I want to use Resources.PhishMeIcon this will minimize the amount of install files associated with this solution.  Please forgive me if I am not understanding or presenting my problem accurately.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can pass in a byte array to FileAttachment in my example, using DotNetOpenMail.  If you have to use Outlook Interop, then it looks like you will need to save your embedded resource to a temp file first

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and it is exactly why I am having problems, I am interacting directly with outlook through Interop.  I did suspect that I would have to save and attach the file but since I am new to this stuff I doubted my conclusion.  Thank you for your help I will work on code that saves the resource out, attaches the file, and then cleans up after it is complete.  Unless you have any better ideas, I am all ears.  Thank you again KiwiPiet.